# Why is this answer not deleted?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38866134/i-have-added-a-property-in-my-pojo-to-add-new-column-using-hibernate-but-while-r/38866673#38866673)  answer has six "Recommend Deletion" votes in [Low Quality Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13287526) and a score of 0, but is still not deleted.

I thought, that the system will automatically delete posts with six "Recommend Deletion" votes and a score less than 1, see [Let's get rid of the 10K flag queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226092/310236):

> 4. Task accumulates 6 RecommendDelete + Delete reviews.
>      **Outcome:** mark flags "helpful". If the post scores > 0 then raise DisputedLowQuality mod flag, else just delete post (current behavior).

Why is the answer not deleted?

Comment: Six users disliked the answer, only one of them downvoted it.  Seems like the wrong way to do this.

Comment: It might very well be the wrong approach, @Hans, but you cannot downvote from the review queue. So I'd say those six people chose quite reasonably given the options that they were presented with.

Comment: It is possible to check the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38866673/timeline) to have more info into what happened also. It records events on the post and it shows the undeletion from the OP here (after the deletion from review).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It *was* deleted after the review, but then the author *undeleted* it.

This does raise a *disputed low quality review (auto)* for a moderator to look into, but we have 146 of them in the queue at the moment, so it would have been some time until we got to it.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite: what rule in the deletion system is it that allows an author of a post to single-handedly overrule the review queue? This seems like it would negate practically all of the benefit of the queue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho he might have improved his answer… And if we say "requires improvement before undeletion", users just may do dummy edits to undelete…

Comment: @bwoebi: _"he might have improved his answer"_ -- isn't that something for him and two others to judge? _"And if we say "requires improvement before undeletion", users just may do dummy edits to undelete"_ -- I don't understand what you mean. It's _impossible_ that he might have improved the answer without an edit; with an edit, sure it could be a "dummy edit", but that's why there should be required two other undelete votes besides the author's. You're not explaining why the unilateral undelete was allowed.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Do you prefer users just reposting their answer instead? That has the same effect... It's quite pointless. Also, regarding undeleting, we only have reopen-queues, no undelete-queue for that case.

Comment: @bwoebi There kinda is an undelete queue [in the moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last7days), section "Undelete votes". It's more a list of posts with undelete votes (that you can't sort or filter or anything) but there's at least a bit of something :).

Comment: As of 2014, @PeterDuniho, this had happened [a whopping 849 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227112). For those 849 times, 357 were edited by the author. That suggests that in a most of these (quite small number of) cases, the author is attempting to fix their post.

Comment: @Tunaki just shows the most recent undelete votes though, so you have to have enough luck to encounter someone actually monitoring that

Comment: @bwoebi:  _"Do you prefer users just reposting their answer instead?"_ -- prefer? No. But reposting an answer to the same question is easily noticed by higher-rep users and can be addressed through the usual moderation tools. _"we only have reopen-queues"_ -- so? again, the deleted post is visible to higher-rep users; there is the SOCVR chat room, and of course mod tools include https://stackoverflow.com/tools where you can find existing undelete votes.

Comment: @hichris123: none of that bears any relevance to the question. I never said this represents a major problem, nor that authors don't make at least some minimal effort some of the time (but note that almost 15% of the time, they _didn't_). Even if the author makes some effort to improve, it seems reasonable to me for there to be some oversight by more experiences users.

Comment: Which there is, @Peter, by mods. I suggest you take a closer look at the meta post I linked, starting with "The reason this hasn't been fixed yet is twofold." Should answer your question on why the system works that way.